# Matrix notation of cartan structure equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, curvature, tensor-calculus

I'm learning about the cartan structure equations through the Gravitation book of MTW. I'm reading chapter 14 and in excercise 14.9 there is a matrix notation defined. Let $e = (\mathbf{e_1},...,\mathbf{e_1})$ be a row vector whose entries are basis vectors and $\omega$ be a column of basis 1-forms $\mathbf{\omega^{\mu}}$. Also let $\Omega = \mathbf{\omega^{\mu}_{\nu}}$ and $\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{R^{\mu}_{\nu}}$ be square matrices with 1-form and 2 form entries. Thus it is possible to write $$d\mathbf{e_{\mu}}=\mathbf{e_{\nu}}\mathbf{\omega^{\nu}_{\mu}}$$ and $$dP=\mathbf{e_\mu}\mathbf{\omega^{\mu}}.$$ Where $P$ is a point on spacetime.

It is asked to derive the equation 
$$d \omega + \Omega \wedge\omega = 0 $$

There is a solution given for the excercise which I don't understand.

$$d^2P = 0 $$

Then

$$0=d^2 P = de \wedge \omega + e d\omega = e(\Omega \wedge \omega + d\omega) $$

What I don't understand is why in the second equality it is possible to "factorize" the $e$ from the first term. Why can I pull it out as if it were a scalar from the wedge product?